# How to calculate the average vectors representing each document using pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, word2vec

I'm new to pyspark and I want to cluster a set of documents (20 clusters). In order to do that I need to do the following:

- Find the word2vec representation.
- map each document to a vector which is the average of the vectors representing the words in the document.
- Preform the clustering.

So I created the word2vec representation but I didn't manage to map each document to its corresponding vector using spark.

I tried the following:

```
from pyspark.mllib.feature import Word2Vec
word2vec = Word2Vec()
model = word2vec.fit(docs)
dic = model.getVectors()

import numpy as np
def calcAverage(x, dic):
    ans = np.zeros(100)
    for word in x: 
        if word in dic:
            ans += np.array(dic[word])
    return tuple(ans / len(x))

vectors = docs.map(lambda x: calcAverage(x, dic))
vectors.collect()
```

But it's not working, the code fails at this line: `vectors = docs.map(lambda x: calcAverage(x, dic))`, any suggestions?

I got the following error:

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o73192.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can you include any error messages from the line where the code is failing?

Comment: I added the error..